# get nth Object stored in a binary file

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

[Java 9]

While trying to store many objects into a binary file by serialization, I came into an issue where I could not directly read the 50th object, and the best way I thought of fixing the issue was looping through all of the objects in the file and then picking the one I wanted. This is of course, very inefficient, and I was thinking if there was any better way to do this. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Are you serializing the objects one at a time? If so, how would you know where in the file the nth object starts? How many objects are you talking about, given you think efficiency matters? If a lot, you should consider using a database, e.g. a NoSQL store.

Comment: There are several ways you could do this. For example, you could serialize them one at a time, first in memory to find out the length, and prefix each serialized object in the file with the length of the object, so you could quickly skip over the ones you don’t need when reading. There are other options too. But SO isn’t a good site for questions for broad questions like this that can have many very different answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no better way to do this. Serialized data is serial in nature, not random-access, and depends on data earlier in the stream, and, of course, on the stream header. See the Protocol section of the Object Serialization Specification.

You have to call`readObject()` *N* times to get the *N*th object.